# How to put a Imageview in to mobile application [XAMARIN,ANDROID]

Tags: android, android-imageview, xamarin

I want to put an imageview on the screen but. It gave "object reference null" exception. I think that I have a logical error. please help me to find it.

Here is my code :

My layout xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/changeImage"/>  
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sampleviewer"
    android:src="@drawable/sampleimage"        
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>   

    </LinearLayout>
```

In OnCreate Function :

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        //Create the user interface in code
        var layout = new LinearLayout (this);
        layout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        var aLabel = new TextView (this);
        aLabel.Text = "Hello, Xamarin.Android";

        var aButton = new Button (this);      
        aButton.Text = "Say Hello";
        aButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
            aLabel.Text = "Hello from the button";
        };  

        var button = new Button (this);
        button.Text = "AAAAAA";


        button.Click += delegate {

            aLabel.Text = " PRESS THE BUTTON";
            var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.sampleviewer); // After this line imageView variable is still null
            imageView.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.sampleimage);
        };

        layout.AddView (aLabel);
        layout.AddView (aButton);           
        layout.AddView (button);
        SetContentView (layout);


   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building your layout in two different ways here.

1. You have an XML layout containing your `ImageView`, but you never reference that XML layout anywhere in code, so Android never loads it (and therefore you can't access it).
2. You also create a layout in Java code by creating a new `LinearLayout` object and adding other views to it. This layout has no `ImageView`.

When you call `SetContentView()` here:

```
SetContentView (layout);
```

You're telling Android to use the layout you created in code. If you want to use the XML layout, you can change to:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

(Replacing `Main` with the actual name of your XML file.)

Otherwise, you'd need to add the `ImageView` in your Java code. But you probably don't want to mix and match XML layouts with Java code layouts.

Also note that you must call `SetContentView()` before calling `FindViewById()`.

You might also want to read through Xamarin's [Resource Layouts](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/resource_layouts/) tutorial.